# Idiom/expression to describe an instance where one makes something seem bigger than it really is

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for idiom/expression to describe an instance where one makes something seem bigger than it really is like if someone making things bigger than they are, exaggerating or overstating a situation.

Comment: So many duplicates: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=make+a+mountain+out+of+a+molehill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for exaggerating a response](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472600/word-for-exaggerating-a-response)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the more common idiom is: [make a mountain out of a molehill](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/make-a-mountain-out-of-a-molehill):

> to make a slight difficulty seem like a serious problem:

> - You're making a mountain out of a molehill. You wrote one bad essay - it doesn't mean you're going to fail.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Just what I needed! Is it more common in British or American English? I guess British, isn't it?

Comment: @Adam - yes, but it is understood.

Answer (score 0):

You might like this idiom

**make heavy weather of**

> To exaggerate the difficulty of something to be done

[American Heritage Dictionary]